# How to shutdown narrator windows phone in lockscreenmodus?

Tags: 8.1, narrator

I can't use my phone because I activate the narrator on my WP, it was great, and eventually I locked my phone... 
Now I can't go in my WP unless I turn off the narrator without needing my password (I think), because when I try windows flag + volume button up, I have to enter my code but I can't type my code because it's on narratormodus...

Anyone who can help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced this situation.
Keep calm and you have to touch any button for longer time. Coz it is for blind people. When they first touch the screen it says what it is... When you touch any button for longer time... It will be accessed. So instead of touching one time you you have to press longer time...i hope this will help you. Coz it worked for me well.

Answer (score -1):

to shut the narrator off hold the volume key and windows button for a while untile the narrator doesnt confirms that the narrator exists..